# C# - Calling C++ crashes program

Tags: c#, c++, dll, crash, dllimport

I am trying to learn how to call C++ code from C#. I am on a Windows 64 bit machine. I have a project which looks like this:

[image: Project structure]

In funcs.cpp:

```
#include <cstdint>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int32_t addInt32(int32_t a, int32_t b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) int32_t subInt32(int32_t a, int32_t b)
    {
        return (a - b);
    }
}

// g++ cpp\funcs.cpp -o cpp\funcs.dll -shared
```

In Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal static class Program
{
    private const string DllPath = "cpp\\funcs.dll";

    [DllImport(DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern Int32 addInt32(Int32 a, Int32 b);

    [DllImport(DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern Int32 subInt32(Int32 a, Int32 b);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(addInt32(10, -5));
        Console.WriteLine(subInt32(15, 12));
    }
}

// dotnet build cs
// dotnet run --project cs
```

The executed commands:

```
C:\Practice\CallCppFromCs>g++ cpp\funcs.cpp -o cpp\funcs.dll -shared
C:\Practice\CallCppFromCs>dotnet build cs
C:\Practice\CallCppFromCs>dotnet run --project cs
```

For some reason, the C# program crashes without even throwing an exception whenever an imported function is called. File.Exists returns true for the dll, so it is there, the function signatures look exactly the same. And it seems that it does not matter if the function in the dll exists or not, since using function names that don't exist has the same result.

What is happening?

Edit: Also, it seems to work on other computers, just not on mine.

Comment: Did you look into eventviewer? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/inside/event-viewer

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: *"without even throwing an exception"* - How would you know? You don't attempt to catch anything.

Comment: Things get "nasty" very quickly when you pass pointers from C# into C++. C# garbage collector can move objects around even when C++ is working on it. (Lookup pinning). 
In general I stay away (from the limited support) DllImport/PInvoke provides. And write explicit interop code in C++/cli (managed C++). So you can control when to copy data from managed memory to the heap, and when to translate C++ exceptions into .Net exceptions. See this [introduction to C++/cli in less then 10 minutes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes).

Comment: Do you have any better luck if you use **CL.EXE** instead of **g++**?

Comment: Why are you using C#?  I recommend using only one language; mixing C# and C++ is difficult and IMHO, a waste of time.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: That would be a very valid concern if there were any pointers involved.  But there aren't in OP's code.

Comment: @madreflection If there was an exception there would be a message?? Also, putting the code inside a try block with a catch that logs the exception message results in nothing, so no exeptions.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Executing it in Visual Studio results in `The program "[12808] cs.exe" was ended with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No special reason, I just wanted to learn how do programmers mix up different languages in a single project. It's not like it's a real application that will be used by someone.

Comment: Put the dll in the same directory as the executable and use a debugger

Comment: @BenVoigt I am aware, but these kind of "toy" examples have a tendency to grow (when used in real products) and then suddenly there are "unexplainable" random crashes.

Comment: Might be worth specifying the calling convention in the C++ code